# expo v48 remote debugging w hermes

Tags: react-native, debugging, expo, remote-debugging

i'm trying to setup remote debugging for my expo app. i'm currently on sdk v48.

i've noticed that bc of usage of reanimated lib, `hermes` js engine is used, but need to connect it to `react-native-debugger` in order to debug redux state.

when simply opened via `› Press j │ open debugger` from the menu, it starts new chrome window but without any of installed extensions like: redux devtools.

recently [a new lib was introduced](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/issues/573#issuecomment-1533894331) which is allowing usage of `react-native-debugger` with `hermes` engine, but that didn't work either, can't pass `pending` status:

[image]
i'm making sure RND is listening on port `19000` as described in https://docs.expo.dev/debugging/tools/#react-native-debugger.

also tried running expo app via dev-client like `npx expo start --dev-client` and accessing on port `8081` via `react-native-debugger` or via http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/ but still can't access to my redux state. it says `status:waiting for client..`

any ideas what i might be doing wrong?

Comment: it seems like expo heard our voices and did some upgrades regarding debugging and expo devtools in js debugging mode.
 `Additionally, React devtools is now built-in to Expo CLI: you can launch it by pressing shift+m and then selecting “Start React devtools"`

Comment: expo sdk 49 https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-49-c6d398cdf740

Answer (score 0):

add "jsEngine": "jsc" in app.json :

```
    "expo": {
    "name": "Barber",
    "slug": "Barber",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "jsEngine": "jsc",
.
.
.
}
```